# Что показывается в блоке Важное на мете?

Tags: поддержка, блок-важных-вопросов

Собственно, обнаружил ссылку на metaSE - вроде уже второй раз. Решил наконец поинтресоваться, а что же тут отображается, а то всегда думал, что только с этой меты.

[image: Важное на мете]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если "вопрос" на [сетевой мете](http://meta.stackexchange.com) имеет метку [featured](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured), он показывается на всех сайтах Stack Exchange. Обычно это не столь "вопросы" сколько объявления -- в данном случае, о переходе с [одной](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) лицензии [на другую](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT), касательно кода, опубликованного пользователями на сайтах сети.

К слову, на португальском сайте это же объявление [было переведено](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4685) и размещено на местной мете.